# Create named lists in a loop R

Tags: r, list, loops

I am generating a number of n lists in a loop, say they were 2.

```
list_1 <- list()
list_2 <- list()

list_all<- list(list_1  = list_1, list_2 = list_2)

list_holder <- list()

i = 100 (some length)


for(j in 1:2)
for(i in length(x)){

list_holder[i] <- *do something*

}

list_all[j] <- list_holder
list_holder <- list() 

}
```

Well, it does not work. It puts the first list i create in the i-loop into list_all, but won't put the second

the warning message is something like :

> Warning message: In list_all[1] <- list_2 :
>    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

If i do it per "hand" and use this indexing : list_all$list_1, i could fill in the newly generated lists, but i dont know how to use $ indexing in a loop.

Thanks for any help. I guess its probably super easy to solve this.

Comment: Try using the double brackets `list_holder[[i]] <- *something*`.

Answer (score 0):

As @niko said usually using double brackets works. However, I recommend you using apply family functions as lapply, tapply, etc. What do you want to do exactly? Is the *do something* using an element from the list_all? If you specify what you want to do exactly we could try to give you a more detailed answer.